# Listing artifacts by version in Artifactory Generic Feed repository

Tags: artifactory, package-repository

I am trying to find the artifact information for a specific version in an Artifactory Generic Feed.

The api endpoint `/api/versions/{repo}/_any?listFiles=1` will only return the latest version, but I would like to be able to get this for any specific version

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "artifacts": [
        {
            "repo": "generic-repo",
            "path": "com/org/TestWebApp2/TestWebApp2-2.0.0.zip",
            "downloadUri": "https://org.jfrog.io/artifactory/generic-repo/com/org/TestWebApp2/TestWebApp2-2.0.0.zip",
            "uri": "https://org.jfrog.io/artifactory/generic-repo/com/org/TestWebApp2/TestWebApp2-2.0.0.zip"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I list all the available versions via `https://org.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/search/versions?g=com.org&a=TestWebApp2`, I get:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "version": "2.0.0",
            "integration": false
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "integration": false
        }
    ]
}
```